# Resolve Firefox dpkg error when reinstalling

Tags: apt, firefox, dpkg

I wanted to delete Firefox without much experience with Linux. I wanted Chrome to be my default browser, but it doesn't show up on Settings, so I searched with the file explorer 'firefox' and deleted all. Now I want to reinstall it, but it gives me this error message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install firefox 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firefox is already the newest version (61.0.1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up firefox (61.0.1-1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/firefox doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package firefox (--configure):
 installed firefox package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 firefox
Configuring sandbox profiles....
Sandbox profiles updated!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`apt-cache policy firefox` output

`$apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 61.0.1-1
  Candidate: 61.0.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 61.0.1-1 1001
       1001 http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: You should never just delete files from applications that come with Ubuntu or are installed with dpkg or apt. Use apt to remove them.

Comment: I understood this, does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install  --reinstall firefox` ?

Comment: It gives me <code>Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package firefox is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  parrot-interface-common

E: Package 'firefox' has no installation candidate
</code>

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy firefox` to the question and specify your Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file called firefox on your desktop (at `~/Desktop`) and copy the following text into it.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# Firefox launcher containing a Profile migration helper for
# temporary profiles used during alpha and beta phases.

# Authors:
#  Alexander Sack <asac@jwsdot.com>
#  Fabien Tassin <fta@sofaraway.org>
#  Steve Langasek <steve.langasek@canonical.com>
#  Chris Coulson <chris.coulson@canonical.com>
# License: GPLv2 or later

MOZ_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/firefox
MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER=`which $0`
MOZ_APP_NAME=firefox

export MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER

while [ ! -x $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME ] ; do
    if [ -L "$MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER" ] ; then
        MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER=`readlink -f $MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER`
        MOZ_LIBDIR=`dirname $MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER`
    else
        echo "Can't find $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME"
        exit 1
    fi
done

usage () {
    $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME -h | sed -e 's,/.*/,,'
    echo
    echo "      -g or --debug          Start within debugger"
    echo "      -d or --debugger       Specify debugger to start with (eg, gdb or valgrind)"
    echo "      -a or --debugger-args  Specify arguments for debugger"
}

moz_debug=0
moz_debugger_args=""
moz_debugger="gdb"

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        -h | --help )
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        -g | --debug )
            moz_debug=1
            shift
            ;;
        -d | --debugger)
            moz_debugger=$2;
            if [ "${moz_debugger}" != "" ]; then
          shift 2
            else
              echo "-d requires an argument"
              exit 1
            fi
            ;;
        -a | --debugger-args )
            moz_debugger_args=$2;
            if [ "${moz_debugger_args}" != "" ] ; then
                shift 2
            else
                echo "-a requires an argument"
                exit 1
            fi
            ;;
        -- ) # Stop option processing
            shift
            break
            ;;
        * )
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ $moz_debug -eq 1 ] ; then
    case $moz_debugger in
        memcheck)
            debugger="valgrind"
            ;;
        *)
            debugger=$moz_debugger
            ;;
    esac

    debugger=`which $debugger`
    if [ ! -x $debugger ] ; then
        echo "Invalid debugger"
        exit 1
    fi

    case `basename $moz_debugger` in
        gdb)
            exec $debugger $moz_debugger_args --args $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME "$@"
            ;;
        memcheck)
            echo "$MOZ_APP_NAME has not been compiled with valgrind support"
            exit 1
            ;;
        *)
            exec $debugger $moz_debugger_args $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME "$@"
            ;;
    esac
else
    exec $MOZ_LIBDIR/$MOZ_APP_NAME "$@"
fi
```

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/firefox /usr/bin/
```

The results of `apt-cache policy firefox` show that Firefox is still installed. Remove everything that Firefox installed and reinstall Firefox.

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq firefox # remove existing firefox package   
sudo apt install firefox
```

Comment: ran without problems $sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq firefox
(Reading database ... 463988 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing firefox (61.0.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.61) ...

Comment: a bit long so.. https://pastebin.com/kGAs4mdu

Comment: thank you so much for the code, now sudo apt install works but i can't run firefox.. https://pastebin.com/uZPDUKKR